Excel statement that updates only once
I have one cell that indicates the status of a project. And then multiple other columns that are intended to mark the date of when the project changes status.



Status
Date Project New
Date Project Uploaded
Date Project Completed




New
=IF(A2="New",NOW(),"")
=IF(A2="Uploaded",NOW(),"")
=IF(A2="Completed",NOW(),"")



The issue is when the status column changes then the date that was recorded in previous stages is now erased. How can i setup a formula (or set of formulas in hidden columns if needed) that will record the day and then lock so it wont change anymore even after Status has changed?
I have tried the above formulas but clearly those dont work. I have looked up circular references to see if that will help but I dont think its a good long term solution especially if I need to change the number of iterations of formulas because there are other formulas in the spreadsheet that i dont want impacted.

VBA in a worksheet_change event is the tool for this.  Formula are live.  And while you can do a circular reference it can be problematic and hard to manage if you pass the workbook to others.

I did some more testing yesterday before I saw your reply and came up with something that works but like you said is hard to manage because of the circular reference. My formula is =IF(A2="New",NOW(),B2) Doing the above formula will update the cell to NOW() when status is updated to "New" but once the status moves forward and is changed to anything else that date will be locked in there as the cell will reference itself. Thoughts?

If this is a worksheet only you will use and is temporary then this is an acceptable method as you know you have to allow the circular reference.  But if you are going to share it or this is going to be a long term, then vba like that of vbasic would be the best way to go.

A Worksheet Change: Conditional Timestamps Without Overwriting


Close all visible workbooks. Open a new workbook. Copy your data into a worksheet. Right-click the same worksheet's tab, select View Code and copy the following code to the window that opens in the Visual Basic Editor. Apply a data validation list (dropdown) to A2:A11 and start selecting values from the dropdowns. Test all scenarios you can think of. Give it some time before deciding what to do.
If the code does what is required (if not, describe what is wrong with it so I can fix it) and you're ready to save your original file as a .xlsm or .xlsb file, use the same steps to apply this functionality to your original file.

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    ' The following two arrays must have the same number of items.
    Dim TIME_STAMP_COLUMNS() As Variant: TIME_STAMP_COLUMNS = VBA.Array( _
        "B", "C", "D")
    Dim STATES() As Variant: STATES = VBA.Array( _
        "New", "Uploaded", "Completed")
    
    Dim crg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With Me.Range(TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
        rCount = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then MsgBox "No data found!", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
        Set crg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no changed cells
    
    Dim drg As Range, dcell As Range, tcell As Range, StateIndex As Variant
    
    For Each tcell In trg.Cells
        StateIndex = Application.Match(tcell.Value, STATES, 0)
        If IsNumeric(StateIndex) Then
            Set dcell = tcell.EntireRow _
                .Columns(TIME_STAMP_COLUMNS(StateIndex - 1))
            If Len(CStr(dcell.Value)) = 0 Then
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = dcell
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, dcell)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next tcell
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells found
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' prevent retriggering this code
    drg.Value = Now
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in continuation
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


Thank you so much I appreciate your help (:
